# Why a Tensorflow model is much more bigger when loading into RAM?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, ram

I have a TensorFlow saved model which is about 20 MB. When I load it to prepare for inferencing, it takes a much bigger size of RAM (~400MB) than its size on disk. This model is run on a computer with only CPU. Is there any reason for this?

Comment: maybe your programme has loaded some other things too

Comment: No, even with a program with a single line of code to load the model, the RAM is still be taken about ~400MB

Comment: HI PhmHiu,
Most data when saved on disk is compressed example a jpeg image of 1-2mb when loaded in memory with opencv may become relatively huge,as it is a matrix  of integers or floats now.
Similarly the weights when loaded in memory and arranged in the model architecture may take significantly more space.